# Selecting a version of Laravel when installing with composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have seen there is a new version of Laravel- 4.1 with new documentation in the laravel website. Few things have changed , really but i would like to continue using laravel version 4 for now. Is there any way i can do to install the version 4 and not 4.1 through composer? I'm asking that because version 4.1 is downloaded automatically whenever i run `composer create-project laravel/laravel --pref destination` in my terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify version number after your destination

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist 4.0`

[Composer documentation here](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)

Answer (score 1):

Even better if you add an asterisk after version number (4.2.*): the newest subversion will be installed e.g. 4.2.12 instead of 4.2.0

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name --prefer-dist 4.2.*
```