# Install Laravel 4.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, installation

I need to install archive version of Laravel 4.1 php framework. I tried installing using composer in ubuntu machine by executing the command given below:-

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel /var/www/demo --prefer-dist
```

But it is downloading the latest version 4.2.

How can i download a specific version of this framework by using either composer or phar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel path 4.1
```

This has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20853982/2920716)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. See the list of accepted composer options: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project (just tested: `[RuntimeException]                   
  The "--pref" option does not exist.`

Comment: @DamienPirsy Updated to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Now you're [telling Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) to install the one from `dist` preferibly (which will be the latest stable version)

You can simply change your composer.json file to:

```
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
},
```

to choose your preferred version